# Как из Python передать данные в web-шаблоны ( html-страниц)?

Tags: python, html, веб-программирование

День добрый!

Не так давно начал изучать Python для машинного обучения.
Дополнительно занимаюсь и версткой в web. Хочу Python-ом заменить php.

Как Python встроить в html?
Как на Python создать обмен данных с web-шаблонами ( html-страниц)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Краткий ответ**

Никак. Ну, то есть вообще никак.

---

## **Развернутый ответ**

Такое не возможно ввиду того, что сам HTML не понимает ни одного языка программирования и заставить его понимать невозможно.

HTML - это язык гиперразметки и не более. Он является не более чем структурой и "костями" сайта. Весь CSS и JS накладываются уже поверх и исполняется самим браузером в момент, как он получает ответ от сервера с голым HTML файлом, файлами стилей и т.д.

Как вы уже наверно догадались, браузер тоже не может просто вставить ваш Python код. Он не рассчитан на это. и его так же нельзя заставить понимать Python.

---

### **Тогда что же делать?**

Использовать Python библиотеки и фреймворки, предназначенные для создания сайтов, которые исполнят Ваш Python код и вернут браузеру HTML с подставленными из него значениями.

Сейчас самый удобный, актуальный и подходящий для новичков фреймворк, ***на мой взгляд***, это Django.

Он берет на себя всю заботу об интерпретации Вашего Python кода в понятный бразеру формат. Разумеется, он имеет огромное множество других возможностей, но, если Вам это интересно, Вы сможете и сами о них узнать.

---

Данным ответом я не пропагандирую Django, а лишь пытаюсь дать Вам понять в каком направлении лежит решение Вашей проблемы. Используйте фреймворки.

---

P.S. Если у Вас возник вопрос, а почему тогда PHP может вставляться в HTML, то фишка PHP заключается как раз в том, что он сам по себе и является в этом плане прямым интерпретатором для HTML и точно так же подставляет значения перед отправкой HTML файла браузеру.

Comment: ПОнимаю что такое html, css. Но мы в сам html прописываеи css, php и прекрепить сторонние файлы можно. Думал это можно и для python. 
Фреймворки не интересны. На данном этапе хочу ручками делть.

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik если не секрет, почему не интересны? В чем причина?

Comment: Как уже и было описано, python не поддерживается. Решение "делать ручками" сродни вести галеон одной ложкой или изобретать колесо.

Comment: @Иван Ипатов сейчас надо научиться руками работать, чтоб в "корень" вникнуть, после уже остальными конструкторами пользоваться.

Comment: @Overlordix он ведь используется в web. Даше какие то книги для web разработок. Как тогда? Только через фреймворк? 
Редакторы и библиотеки позволяющие писать скрипты на python знакомы. Как использовать скрипты на путоне в web/html для создания того же функционала. 

Не ужели php еще не заменим. По мне так путон проще пхп

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik "_Но мы в сам html прописываеи css, php_" ... А вот и нет, в html невозможно вписать ничего на php. Потому как код на php исполняется на сервере. А html отрисовывается на клиенте. Все происходит в ровности наоборот, вы в php вписываете html. Т.е. программа на php выполняется на сервере и на выходе она создает html, который web-сервером отдается клиенту. На питоне делается абсолютно то же самое, пишется программа, которая генерит html, который web-сервер отдается клиенту.

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik И конечно можно без фреймверка. Но так как питон в отличие от php создавался как язык общего назначения, а не для работы конкретно с web, то вам надо самому разобрать запрос от браузера и самому соблюсти несколько условностей по передаче созданного ответа web-серверу (который отдаст его клиенту). Начинать изучение данной темы надо с WSGI - это прослойка между web-сервером и вашим скриптом на питоне. И для начала надо выбрать какой именно wsgi использовать. Их примерно десяток разных. Я например предпочитаю bjoern, он вроде как по тестам самый быстрый и мне с nginx его удобно дружит

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik Но это потому, что мне как раз надо что бы быстро работало и я предпочитаю что бы мое питон приложение было постоянно запущено и крутилось в ОЗУ, быстро отвечая на запросы. Есть другие wsgi движки, которые делают питон приложение более похожим на php: запрос пришел, скрипт запустился, ответ создал, завершился.

Comment: @Mike  не это гдлавное - php in html or  html in php. Главное - имея html могу вписать скрипт php. Теперь хочу в html вписать Python, вот это и хочу понять - как?

Comment: @Mike Вот, спасибо. Есть еще что то интересно на подобии?  "Начинать изучение данной темы надо с WSGI"

Но все же  в html вписать Python. Как Python из внешнего файла подключается.

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik "_не это главное - php in html or html in php_". Если вам хочется на низком уровне, то понимание этого как раз очень важно. PHP это язык который изначально был создан именно для быстрой разработки web-приложений и в нем все под это заточено. Отработана связка веб-сервер - язык. Весь разбор запроса и процедуры выдачи результата клиенту спрятаны под капотом. Разметка html встроена в синтаксис языка и вам _кажется_, что достаточно вписать одно в другое. В питоне обычно всю эту работу выполняют фреймверки. Вы хотите без них, поэтому берете доку на WSGI и остальное делаете сами

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik По большому счету можно и без WSGI, но тогда ваше питон приложение должно быть заодно веб-сервером.

Comment: @Mike хорошо. ОКунусь в WSGI  чтоб понять основу. Благодарю.
Сами, что, php или python предпочитаете в работе с web или от задачи зависит?

Просто понимаю что python проще в синтаксисе, и уже видел теже книги где python в web. Так понимаю замена  идет.

Comment: @Mike просто год назад сунулся в изучение pytho, numpy, pandas и прочее что относится к машинному обучнию. В тоже время мне нужен php (изучить глубже ) .
Но, 2 языка учить это не легко. Вижу что python используется в веб. Поэтому задал начальный вопрос. чтоб Python учить и для машинного обучения, и для веб, а с рнр уйти

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132587/discussion-between-tryd0g0lik-and-mike).